# Java list items

Tags: java, list

Im using the following code

```
List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
text.add("Hello");
```

So that list will only accept Strings to be added, how can I add into one list more types of variables like ints and strings together like

Adding into the text list some rectangle values like

**rectangle name, rectangle width, rectangle height**

So later I can access them in a loop

Comment: Why do you want to do that? would it not be better to write a class with those variables as fields?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create your own `Rectangle` class and store those values in it.

```
List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();
rectangles.add(new Rectangle("Foo", 20, 30));
```

Comment: Better if he stores Rectangle in ArrayList<Rectangle> rather then store only rectangle name.

Comment: Yeah I was commenting your post saying that he should store name of rec in ArrayList and that was a bit strange cause you can store whole object and that is exactly what did you add recently :)

Answer (score 4):

Expanding a bit on Duncan's answer, here is how you might create a Rectangle class:

```
public class Rectangle {
    private String name;
    private int height;
    private int width;

    /** 
     * Create a rectangle by calling 
     *   Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle("foo", 20, 10);
     */
    public Rectangle(String name, int height, int width) {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }
}
```

You would need to add accessor methods to it, so that you can retrieve the name, width, and height. These are usually public methods that are named things like getName and getWidth (nicknamed *getters*). You might also have a function that returns the area. Here's an example.

```
public String getName() { return name; } 
public int getHeight() { return height; } 
public int getWidth() { return width; } 

public String area() {
    int area = height * width;
    return "Rectangle " + name + " has an area " + area + ".";
}
```

Comment: Yup. And if one really wanted, they could also wrap a [`java.awt.Rectangle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) object in this class to encapsulate the height and width (if that class's functionality was desired).

Comment: Good point, Paul. The class would also provide an origin, should the OP ever need it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a `class` which will contain the variables you need, and use that class as the data type in the `list`declaration.

**e.g.:**

```
class MyStructure{
  int anInteger;
  double aDouble;
  string aString;
  //Followed by any other data types you need.   

  //You create a constructor to initialize those variables.
  public MyStructure(int inInt, double inDouble, string inString){
     anInteger = inInt;
     aDouble = inDouble;
     aString = inString;
  }
}
```

Then when you have your main or your method, and declare a list you simply write:

```
List<MyStructure> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new MyStructure(5, 2.5, "Hello!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer to create a class is certainly a better way to organize your program, the answer to your question is to create a list of type Object. Then you can add items to your list of any type. To determine which type you are dealing with at run time, you can use the instanceof keyword. But to be perfectly clear, this is not good practice.

```
List<Object> text = new ArrayList<String>();
text.add("Hello");
text.add(new Integer(10));
```